# Are there best practices on using rolling vs. historic timeframe in generating business reports?

Tags: user-expectation, design-patterns, time, business-application, reports

I'm working on a reports dashboard for IT Admin users. I need to make a UX recommendation on date range for the reports, and am trying to understand what is best for these expert users: Rolling data (i.e. last 30 days), or Historical data (Last calendar month) - or show both.

Are there industry standards or heuristics around why/when to use one or the other?

Thank you for your insight!

Answer (score 1):

Well it's up to you, but the biggest difference between the two approaches is that a rolling date range you don't really have to paginate unless they want to see farther back.

And the downside of a calendar month approach is that at the start of the month, you will probably not have any / enough data, and pagination is required.

For data analysis it's probably better to use a rolling date, so that the user will be more likely to find what he wants without redirecting to the month he/she wants.

For calendar-related stuff i'd say go with a calendar month approach.

If your app already has something that filters by date, you should prefer to use whatever that did to be consistent.